# Spring Batch FlatFileItemReader populating field value across all items/lines read

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am reading a flat file using spring batch `FlatFileItemReader`.

I have a `requestId` field which i need to populate with a unique value for all records read from the flat file.
 eg: When i read file1. I want to set the `requestId` to 1 for all Item objects created at requestId field. For file2, i need to set requestId to 2.

my requestId is uniquely generated by a separate class.

How can I achieve this using spring batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some possible solutions

use an [ResourceAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ResourceAware.html) Item

```
public class MyItem implements ResourceAware {

    private Resource resource;

    public String getId() {
        return createIdFromResource(resource);
    }

    private String createIdFromResource(final Resource resource) {
        // create your ID here
        return resource.getFilename();
    }

    @Override
    public void setResource(final Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }
}
```

use an [Listener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#interceptingStepExecution) (here with interfaces, less verbose use of annotations is possible too)

```
public class TestListener implements StepExecutionListener, ItemReadListener<String> {
    private StepExecution stepExecution;
    private static final String CURRENT_ID = "currentId";

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeRead() {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterRead(final String item) {
        String currentId = null;
        if (stepExecution.getExecutionContext().containsKey(CURRENT_ID)) {
            currentId = stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getString(CURRENT_ID);
        } else {
            String fileName = stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getString("fileName");
            // ... create ID from FileName
            currentId = fileName + "foo";
            stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put(CURRENT_ID, currentId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadError(final Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

in the above example the current fileName is avavailable in the stepExecutionContext, it might be you have to pull it from jobParameters and extract the filename

```
String paramValue = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters().getString("paramName");
// extract fileName from paramValue
```

Comment: I used the StepListener and it worked like a beauty. Thanks